Row-level security in Google Cloud Spanner
Looking at the fine-grained access control options in Spanner I would also like the option to use row-level security, similar to PostgreSQL.
In a multi-tenant system it would be nice to rely on built-in security features without having to resort to one of the strategies described here. Sure, they will work but maintaining separate instances, schemas or databases would present significant administrative problems, particularly related to schema migration.
Since it's not mentioned in the core documentation I'm assuming it's not possible but I've been unable to find a full PostgreSQL compatibility report for Spanner so I'm still hoping. Does anyone have any insight into this?

I never heard about RLS in Spanner. I just found this, and I don't know if you can bend this mechanism to achieve what your want. https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/rest/v1/Policy

Upon checking the Spanner public issue and feature requests tracker, I found no existing feature request related to Spanner row-level security. I suggest you file a new request so that the Spanner team can look into it and have discussions about it.
Also for the PostgreSQL compatibility report for Spanner, you might consider checking the release notes as an alternative, where you’ll find a list of features that Spanner supports specific to PostgreSQL.
